# Freehub removal

Tags: repair, freewheel, spokes, freehub

I need to remove this freehub (see picture), to replace a broken spoke, however, it is an old bike and I am unsure how to proceed? I've managed to removed the cassette using a chain whip and a 32mm lockring tool.

I do have smaller lockring tool that fits the notch, but it is really tights and do not seem to move at all. Is it even this part I need to loosen to get it off? I can't find any similar freehubs online.. [image: freehub]
[image: gears]

Comment: Not a freehub. Looks like a classic freewheel. Try the shimano freewheel tool in those splines and unscrew anti-clockwise.

Comment: https://assets.onbuy.com/i10/product/2646c66c90994bf5bf70f19600c1efa6-o11003208/shimano-tl-fw30-multiple-freewheel-tool.jpg

Comment: @Noise that's a totally valid answer.

Comment: @Luna what kind of cassette was it?  That strange three-level step is quite odd.  Can you add any of the label text etc?

Comment: @Criggie that's how most sprockets on a threaded freewheel are laid up, with the steps.

Comment: I would write up an answer, but it has to be better than a 1 liner

Comment: @noise  fair point, though right now there's no answer, so even one line+photo is better than nothing. Sometimes a short answer is all that there is to say.

Comment: Hi and thanks for alle your replies. @noise it might be a freewheel - I am pretty new to the bike-world. I've unscrewed great using a cassette tutorial?

Comment: @Criggie it says "Tracer".. not anything I can find online?

Comment: And @Noise yes I actually have that tool and it fits. But it seems to be REALLY stuck. And I am scared to do something wrong.

Comment: I've just added an extra picture of how it looked before removing the gears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a neat freeWHEEL that has removable/replaceable cogs.  I've never seen one like that in person.

The standard technique is to use the shimano freewheel spline driver tool, and a big 12" or larger adjustable spanner.  That's enough about a third of the time

In my experience, the reliable technique is to go straight to a well-mounted bench vise.  Clamp the tool in the vise so the splines point upward, lower the wheel down so the splines engage, and then use the full diameter of the rim as leverage.  It will unscrew anticlockwise when viewed from above.

It can help to imagine you're trying to spin a large heavy barrel which is on it's end.   As for being stuck, this unit has been tightened every time you push a pedal, so yes it will be quite tight.

I've never had the vise trick fail, but its possible there's corrosion and galling in the threads, so some penetrating oil might help too.

---

It may be hard to find replacement cogs, so you might choose to buy a common freewheel for daily use, and store this weird old one for a future rebuild.

Comment: I FINALLY got it off with using a bench vise and help from some extra muscles (we had to be two people turning the wheel). The bike is not up and running again. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Luna okay great work!   When you reassemble, put a light coat of grease on the threads to help the next person.  Likely whoever assembled your wheel didn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Measure & count number of splines, then search on temu or Amazon. I've had some luck on both. I weld so I have fabricated my own in obsolete situations.  I do not think that your is obsolete so good luck.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. Anyone can search the internet, so based on the pictures posted by the questioner, do you have a more substantial answer, such as "This is the tool I found to solve your problem" - and then give a part or model number of the tool.

Comment: Sorry. I'll try to do better